# Где можно разместить примеры php/Laravel работ

Tags: php, laravel, хостинг

У меня есть портфолио, залитое на github pages. Но как известно github pages не поддерживает server side языки. Что можете посоветовать. Купить какой-нибудь недорогой хостинг и с портфолио ссылки оставить на php/Laravel проекты или портфолио лучше туда же перенести? Либо вообще фотки работ в графе "мои работы" оставить, а на сами работы ссылку на gihub оставить, чтобы скачать могли.
Как это можно реализовать более грамотно?

Comment: Если у вас будет много работ, то лучше всего сделать скриншот работоспособности и оставить ссылку на гитхаб, больше не требуется. Если у вас какой-то большой проект и вы хотите его развивать, то конечно лучше купить хостинг и разместить его с полным функционалом на нем.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недорогой хостинг - это хорошая идея.
Сам я лично подключил github pages + server side используя **iframe**, [вот](https://github.com/dionisvl/dionisvl.github.io/blob/master/index.html).

Кроме того есть вообще бесплатные сервера:

- *Amazon EC2* - https://seopulses.ru/besplatniy-vps-vds-v-amazon/
- *Oracle Cloud Free Tier* - https://habr.com/ru/post/541466/
- *Google Cloud Platform* - https://seopulses.ru/besplatniy-vps-vds-v-google/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень интересный подход! Единственное, если верить этим статьям, Амазон и Гугл дают сервера всего на год. Что в целом неплохо, но через год либо платить либо опять с настройками возиться для переноса на другой сервер)